# VSCode RemoteSSH - connection timeout

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

Beginning today, I am unable to connect to my remote server in VSCode.  The error in the output shows this repeating 5 times:

```
[15:34:11.799] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+my-server", attempt 5, (Reconnection)
[15:34:11.805] SSH Resolver called for host: my-server
[15:34:11.808] Setting up SSH remote "my-server"
[15:34:11.819] Using commit id "d045a5eda657f4d7b676dedbfa7aab8207f8a075" and quality "stable" for server
[15:34:11.832] Install and start server if needed
[15:34:11.849] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 53101 "myserver" bash
[15:34:11.857] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[15:34:28.879] Resolver error: Error: Connecting with SSH timed out
    at g.Timeout (c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:585348)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (c:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.90.1\out\extension.js:1:679743)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[15:34:28.948] ------
```

The port number in that SSH command is different for each attempt.  If I copy that command out and run it in cmd manually from my local machine and add in `-vvv`, then I see the connection is successful and the prompt sits on "debug2: exec request accepted on channel 2" infinitely.  I can't tell what the problem is.  Is the local forwarding port failing to be created and listen on?  Is there something with the remote server causing the timeout?  Oddly, if I delete the .vscode-server directory on the remote and try to reconnect, then it actually does reinstall it fine.  But I still get the error that VSCode can't connect to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that the VSCode Remote extensions have their own repository.  Turns out my issue is https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/7324

Ensuring that I set `remote.SSH.useLocalServer` to `true` in my user settings.json fixed the issue until it is resolved in-code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting`remote.SSH.useLocalServer` to `false`. the server being Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS.

and ensuring the server has enough memory / RAM did the trick for me.